# Parse.com query

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

have parse.com working perfect with my app and it querys and retrieves geopints no problem.

what i would like to know is when a user scans an nfc tag my application takes these co-ordinates stored on that tag and places markers on a google map, nothing wrong there. but i would like it to query a third string which is being currently being taken in  by my application but how can i get that 3rd string, example "route001" into this parse query :

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("route001");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
```

instead of it querying the same class every time it starts. hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you storing GeoPoints? Which class is it in? And in which way are you binding the String to GeoPoint? 
It looks like you're trying to link the GeoPoint you got from NFC to a String? In that case, if GeoPoint is stored in instance of  a class called "Location", you can simply save the String as another property for the "Location" instance. Then query for Location, and limit the query by String. Code would look similar to this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Location");
[query whereKey:@"stringPropertyName" equalTo:@"exampleString"];
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {...});
```

Comment: My project has since been handed up, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks @Balar, please accept the answer if you liked it :)